# Why my div components in pages is not showing up?

Tags: css, reactjs

```
function BUStudentLinkHome() {
  return <div z-index="1">Home Page</div>;
}

export default BUStudentLinkHome;
```

This is the code I have in pages.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact={true}>
          <BUStudentLinkHome />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Layout>
  );
}
```

This is the code I have in App.js, Everything works fine, the routing is working, the Layout component is showing up, with the navbar and the profile components. But the text I have in the BUHomepage "This is the home page" is not showing up when it is AT the home page, but I have already linked the pages to the app js, so I don't know why it isn't showing up. Also another question, if I want to style the CSS in the specific pages, where can I add the styling? Do I create another CSS file or can I do inline.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding it as a component like this?

```
<Switch>
   <Route path={"/"} exact={true} component={BUStudentLinkHome} />
</Switch>
```

Comment: Just did, but the div is still not showing up

Comment: Oh, and add your z-index through style:

`<div style={{z-index: 1}}>Home Page</div>`

Comment: It is still not showing up, even after editing the z-index. So I checked, it;s not the routing, it is just under the Navbar, but even after putting it on top, it's not showing up.